# bitbucket pipelines artifact published and extracted but not visible

Tags: cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I have following pipeline:

```yaml
pipelines:
  custom:
    build:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: scan for secrets
          runs-on:
          - 'self.hosted'
          - 'linux'
          script:
          - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.5.1
      - step:
          name: build
          image:
            name: gradle:8.1.1
          caches:
          - gradle
          runs-on:
          - 'self.hosted'
          - 'linux'
          script:
          - gradle build -x test
          - mkdir -p $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/dist
          - cp build/libs/app.jar $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/dist/
          - ls -la dist
          after-script:
          - pipe: atlassian/checkstyle-report:0.3.0
          artifacts:
            paths:
            - dist/**
      - step:
          name: test
          runs-on:
          - 'self.hosted'
          - 'linux'
          image:
            name: gradle:8.1.1
          caches:
          - gradle
          script:
          - gradle test
    - step:
        name: dockerize
        runs-on:
        - 'self.hosted'
        - 'linux'
        image:
          name: xxx.com/kaniko:v1.12.1-debug-4
          username: $USERNAME
          password: $PASSWORD
        size: 2x
        script:
        - pwd
        - ls -la
        - find . -iname '*.jar'
        - ./devops/pipelines/scripts/kaniko-login.sh
        - /kaniko/executor --cache=true --cache-copy-layers=true --cache-repo="$DOCKER_DOMAIN/lalala/cache" --context="$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR" --dockerfile="$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/Dockerfile" --destination="$DOCKER_DOMAIN/lalala:latest" --destination="$DOCKER_DOMAIN/lalala:$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER" --use-new-run --snapshot-mode=redo
```

And I have kaniko error:

```
error building image: error building stage: failed to optimize instructions: failed to get files used from context: failed to get fileinfo for /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/dist/app.jar: lstat /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/dist/app.jar: no such file or directory
```

As you can already see I tried to debug it so:

- in `build` step on `ls -la` command:

  ```
  + ls -la dist
  total 58312
  drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     4096 Jul 12 11:07 .
  drwxrwxrwx 9 root root     4096 Jul 12 11:07 ..
  -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 59700452 Jul 12 11:07 app.jar
  ```
- also in `build` step in teardown part:

  ```
  Searching for files matching artifact pattern dist/**
  Artifact pattern dist/** matched 1 files with a total size of 56.9 MiB
  Compressed files matching artifact pattern dist/** to 52.2 MiB in 1 seconds
  Uploading artifact of 52.2 MiB
  Successfully uploaded artifact in 4 seconds
  ```
- and I can see artifact in Artifacts tab and I can download it.
- then in `dockerrize` step in build setup part:

  ```
  Artifact "dist/**": Downloading
  Artifact "dist/**": Downloaded 52.2 MiB in 3 seconds
  Artifact "dist/**": Extracting
  Artifact "dist/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
  ```
- also in `dockerize` step in find command output:

  ```
  + find . -iname '*.jar'
  ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
  ```

  so no `dist`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a problem. Even if `dockerize` step is saying:

```
Artifact "dist/**": Downloading
Artifact "dist/**": Downloaded 52.2 MiB in 3 seconds
Artifact "dist/**": Extracting
Artifact "dist/**": Extracted in 0 seconds
```

it fails silently because `kaniko` container doesn't have `tar` etc. When I changed image into one created with this:

```
FROM gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.12.1-debug as kaniko

FROM atlassian/default-image:4.20230308

COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/.docker /kaniko/.docker
ENV DOCKER_CONFIG /kaniko/.docker/
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/executor /kaniko/executor
```

then it worked.

Base issue is (but I do not know where to submit it) that pipeline doesn't ensure that `tar` (and related gzip / bzip2 stuff) is present in container.

Comment: Holy cow! Yeah that should be submitted to Atlasian. Sadly, they deliberately turned the issue reporting into a paternalist anti-pattern design https://bitbucket.org/blog/update-on-how-to-submit-product-feedback and I just moved to GitLab so, good luck.